# Как выбрать из базы часовой пояс из поля типа date?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

```
TRUNC(TO_DATE(:sign_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

А как выбрать и часовой пояс, чтобы получилось `06.07.2003 00:00:00 +04:00`?

Comment: Часовой пояс не хранится в базе, время в базе хранится в "нормализированом" формате. Часовой пояс - это параметры вашего sql-клиента или сервера.

Comment: Вопрос зачем вам часовой пояс? Как правило клиентские программы сообщают серверу свой часовой пояс, и сервер тогда делает поправки клиенту на разницу во времени. это реализуется в с# java или других ПО. В браузерах как правило пользователь сам задаёт часовой пояс своей "учётке". В десктопных приложениях пояс смотрят в региональных параметрах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В поле типа `DATE` часовой пояс не хранится.

---

`SYSTIMESTAMP` возвращает дату, включая *time zone*, системы, на которой уастановлена БД. Тип возврата: `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi tzh:tzm') from dual;
```

Сохранить в колонку БД, а в последствии выбрать из неё, информацию о часовом поясе возможно только с типом данных [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-BE23545B-469A-4A57-8D13-505F2F5DB706).

Answer (score 1):

Из поля date выбрать часовой пояс нельзя, ибо он задается переменными окружениями.
Посмотреть какой у вас задан часовой пояс можно так:

```
SELECT TZ_OFFSET(SESSIONTIMEZONE) FROM DUAL;
```